# Cache-Control headers in a Cloudflare Workers site

Tags: cache-control, hugo, static-site, cloudflare-workers

I'm just testing Workers sites with a Hugo-created static site. It already existed, so I used the docs’ instructions for adapting an existing site. The `cache-control` headers for the `woff2` and `css` files all show up with `no-cache`, contrary to what I'd have expected based on https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516#h_a01982d4-d5b6-4744-bb9b-a71da62c160a. The Workers site in question is https://hosts-test-hugo.brycewray.workers.dev/.

I found the following at https://levelup.gitconnected.com/use-cloudflare-javascript-workers-to-deploy-you-static-generated-site-ssg-1c518e078646 but don't know if it's related:

> A Cloudflare Worker is a piece of JavaScript code that runs every time you access a specific route on a website proxied by Cloudflare. The code is executed on every request  *before*  they reach Cloudflare’s cache. This means Worker responses are not cached (although requests made by the worker to other web services might be cached with the appropriate caching headers).

Does the site need to have a custom domain — i.e., rather than being a “.workers.dev” URL — before it will have normal caching behavior? Is that even related?

*[**Note**: I am posting this here because I’ve been unsuccessful in getting a response on either the [Cloudflare community forum](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-set-cache-ttl-for-static-assets-with-workers-sites/150205/5) or the [Cloudflare subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CloudFlare/comments/j6havm/cachecontrol_headers_in_a_workers_site/) — hoping for better results here.]*

Comment: I tried visiting your site and I don't see `cache-control: no-cache` on any of the responses I get back. The css and woff2 files in particular don't seem to have a cache-control header at all, but the cf-cache-status shows they are being cached by Cloudflare. In what context are you seeing `no-cache`?

Comment: @KentonVarda I see this in **Request Headers** in Chrome DevTools. I suppose the issue is why there is no `cache-control` header under **Response Headers**. I see similar results on other sites I know to be Workers Sites. **However**: I now, after many hours of additional searching than I'd already done, am finding more information (in and out of the CF site) that explains this better. Thanks for responding, sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Workers Sites does not serve a `Cache-Control` header, but you can customize it to do so. (**EDIT** to clarify: Workers Sites *are* cached on Cloudflare's edge by default, and support "etags" for revalidation. The `Cache-Control` header controls whether they are also cached *in the browser* without requiring revalidation.)

Note that Workers Sites works very differently from using Cloudflare with a classic origin server. If you're reading something about caching on Cloudflare, but it doesn't specifically mention Workers Sites, then it probably does not apply to Workers Sites.

With Workers Sites, your site is served by a Cloudflare Worker -- code that runs directly on Cloudflare's servers. So, you have no "origin" server behind Cloudflare, and Cloudflare's cache doesn't work in the normal way. The Worker code is completely responsible for serving the content, including setting any headers like `Cache-Control`.

In fact, when you create a new Workers Sites project using `wrangler`, the code for this Worker is generated for you -- but you are allowed to edit it! You can customize the code all you want to do whatever you want. The code for the Worker is found in your project directory under `workers-site/index.js`. The code [looks like this](https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-sites-template/blob/master/workers-site/index.js) -- in fact, it is initialized as a copy of that file from GitHub.

This worker code depends on a library (npm module) called [`@cloudflare/kv-asset-handler`](https://github.com/cloudflare/kv-asset-handler) to do most of the work. This library can be customized to handle caching in various ways through [the `cacheControl` option](https://github.com/cloudflare/kv-asset-handler#cachecontrol).

But where do you set this option? Well, in your worker code!

Open up `workers-site/index.js` and look for the part that [looks like this](https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-sites-template/blob/master/workers-site/index.js#L27-L35):

```js
async function handleEvent(event) {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url)
  let options = {}

  /**
   * You can add custom logic to how we fetch your assets
   * by configuring the function `mapRequestToAsset`
   */
  // options.mapRequestToAsset = handlePrefix(/^\/docs/)
```

The comment mentions one way that you can use `options` to customize how your site is served, but you can also set `cacheControl` here. Try adding this:

```js
  options.cacheControl = {
    browserTTL: 3600      // 1 hour
  }
```

Now re-deploy your site, and you should see assets are served with `Cache-Control: max-age=3600`. Of course, this means that your content may be cached in people's browsers for up to an hour (3600 seconds); you may prefer a longer or shorter period.

Note that if you aren't a programmer, this may all seem a bit daunting. Workers Sites is really designed for people who want to be able to customize how their sites are served by editing JavaScript code. For those not interested in writing code, you will be limited to the default behavior, which may or may not suit your needs.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks again to Cloudflare’s Kenton Varda for his answer here, without which I’d have been totally stuck. I also thank [Brian Li](https://brianli.com) for additional and equally valuable help he provided separately.

Adding the following for others who may find it useful . . .

The remaining problem I encountered was that I didn’t know how to assign differing `cache-control` values (such as one month, or `2592000`) to most of the static assets while leaving the HTML at a much smaller value (like `3600` or `0`). Then, a few days later, I found the answer within [a comment in Issue #81](https://github.com/cloudflare/kv-asset-handler/issues/81#issuecomment-590638007) for the Cloudflare KV-Asset-Handler repository. So, now, I have the following code within my Worker’s `index.js` file:

```js
  options.cacheControl = {
    browserTTL: 0,
    edgeTTL: 0,
    bypassCache: false // default
  }

  const filesRegex = /(.*\.(ac3|avi|bmp|br|bz2|css|cue|dat|doc|docx|dts|eot|exe|flv|gif|gz|ico|img|iso|jpeg|jpg|js|json|map|mkv|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|qt|rar|rm|svg|swf|tar|tgz|ttf|txt|wav|webp|webm|webmanifest|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|zip))$/

  if(url.pathname.match(filesRegex)) {
    options.cacheControl.edgeTTL = 2592000
    options.cacheControl.browserTTL = 2592000
  }
```

If you look at that linked issue comment and wonder what’s different: the only thing is that I removed `html` (and, to be safe, `htm`) from the list of extensions. As a result, my Worker site’s HTML has zero caching while each CSS, font, or image file has a one-month `cache-control` setting — exactly the desired result. **Note**: The vast majority of the site’s images are hosted elsewhere, but I do still host a small number for favicons and fallback in general.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you serve a site using Workers Sites, things work very differently from how they work when you use Cloudflare in front of a regular origin server. I think your links aren't actually relevant to Workers Sites. It seems like the problem here is just that Workers Sites is not sending any `cache-control: max-age`. That actually seem to me like a bug in Workers Sites. You could edit the JavaScript in workers-site/index.js to make it add cache-control headers, but we should probably fix this in the default template too.

Comment: OK it looks like the functionality is there, it's just not enabled by default. I'll post an answer on how to enable it...

Comment: @KentonVarda Greatly appreciated!